# How to read special character as it is from MySQL table into Spring boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, character-encoding

This is a two-column table row output in the MySQL database console

```
> SELECT * FROM PLAYER\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
OBJECT_TYPE: VLC
SCALE: µs
```

The output I get in the Java code is

```
"Object":"VLC", 
"Scale":"�s"
```

I tried this in the configuration file -

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://silver.mg.com:3306/compdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-16
```

I want output in SQL query results in Java as -

```
"Object":"VLC", 
"Scale":"µs"
```

Somehow that special character(µ)is not getting parsed.

Tried with `characterEncoding=UTF-16` and also with `characterEncoding=UTF-8` in the `spring.datasource.url`

Comment: *&characterEncoding=UTF-16* Is that really the case? Please post ```show create table PLAYER```

Comment: Please see last comment. Also, how and where are you displaying the output?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compdb`.`PLAYER` (
  `OBJECT` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SCALE` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

Comment: OK, progress. Now you know it's UTF-8 (as I suspected). Now see my last comment (question)

Comment: I am using that output in http response. But I also checked it locally during debug. The output doesn't seems parsing.

Comment: You're using Windows? ```System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));``` Also print ```"Scale":"µs"```  and see what you get

Comment: That should have been Also print ```"Scale":"\u00B5s"```  and see what you get

Comment: I used these two statements -

System.out.println("file encoding = "+System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println("\"Scale\":\"µs\"");

And here is the output:

file encoding = UTF-8
"Scale":"µs"

Comment: *Are* you running Windows?

Comment: The database and spring boot application is hosted on Linux. My Java editor is on Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248626/discussion-between-g00se-and-p-zankat).